# Url rewrite for tomcat

Tags: java, regex, tomcat, url-rewriting

We have already defined url rule for java application via tomcat rewrite.xml file.

```
<rule>
    <condition name="host" operator="equal">example-laboratories.pt</condition>
    <from>[^pt]/(.*)$</from>
    <to type="redirect">http://example-laboratories.pt/pt/$1</to>
</rule>
```

This works when we request the URL http://example-laboratories.pt url, but I need to redirect to http://example-laboratories.pt/pt if the user requests http://example-laboratories.pt/pt.  Now the above rule redirects to http://example-laboratories.pt/pt/pt (notice the additional 'pt' on the end).

Comment: I didn't _quite_ understand what rewrite you wanted so I can't suggest a solution, but it's for sure a regular expression problem. (That `from` isn't matching what you expect…)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but it looks like you have an error in your regular expression:

```
<from>[^pt]/(.*)$</from>
```

This actually says "any character except 'p' or 't', followed by a slash, then zero or more of anything."

I'm not sure that's what you want, but it doesn't seem like what you want to be doing. You can avoid Regular expressions for the most part if you use a different URL-rewriting tool. (It looks like you are using Tuckey?)

You can do this using OCPsoft Rewrite (http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite/)

For example:

```
ConfigurationBuilder.begin()
.defineRule()
.when(Domain.matches("example-laboratories.pt")
    .and(Path.matches("/{1}/{2}")
        .where("1").matches("(?!pt)[^/]+")
        .where("2").matches(".*")))
.perform(Redirect.permanent(context.getContextPath() + "/pt/{2}"))
```